# SQL JOB reason 193

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I create MSSQL job with console application (operating system - cmdExec), I get error with eason 193.
There is full message:

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. The process could not
>   be created for step 1 of job 0x4CB38CF498AEE244A487876F4746F5A7
>   (reason: 193).  The step failed.

What could be a cause of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gotten this kind of error before or have you successfully created jobs in the past?

It's likely that that specific account doesn't have the permissions necessary to create the job. If you've got access to SQL Server Management Studio, you can use the two links to learn more about the permissions needed (inside of the MSDB database) as well as how to check and set those permissions for a specific account.

- [SQL Agent permissions Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx)
- [Check and set permissions for SQL Agent Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901.aspx)